# How can I align elements across different frames in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am reorganizing the structure of a GUI, and I am having some alignment issues. I have a `LabelFrame` on the left containing a `matplotlib` canvas, and I have a `Notebook` on the right containing several `LabelFrames` in tabs, each containing another `matplotlib` canvas. I want to visually align the internal `LabelFrames` in the `Notebook` to the leftmost `LabelFrame`, so that in the image below, the words "Left Frame" and the lower "Tab 1" are vertically aligned. How can that be done? A (mostly) minimal working example is included below.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        parent.deiconify()
        self.parent = parent

        #define and position the main panel on the left
        self.left_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.parent, text='Left Panel')
        self.left_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

        #define and position the tab-enabled secondary panel on the right
        self.ntbk = ttk.Notebook(self.parent)
        self.ntbk.grid(row=0,column=1)

        #define internal frames for the tabs
        self.tab1_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.ntbk, text='Tab 1')
        self.tab2_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.ntbk, text='Tab 2')

        self.ntbk.add(self.tab1_frame, text='Tab 1')
        self.ntbk.add(self.tab2_frame, text='Tab 2')


        #Left panel children
        #define a figure canvas to go in the left panel
        self.left_f = Figure(figsize=(7,5), dpi=100)
        self.left_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.left_f, master=self.left_frame)
        self.left_toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(self.left_frame)
        self.left_toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.left_canvas, self.left_toolbar_frame)
        self.left_toolbar.update()
        self.left_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.left_toolbar_frame.grid(row=1,column=0)

        #define a control panel for the left panel to go below the figure
        self.left_control_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.left_frame, text='Left Control Panel')
        self.left_control_frame.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)

        self.left_button = tk.Button(self.left_control_frame, text='Button')
        self.left_button.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)


        #notebook children
        #define a figure canvas to go in tab 1
        self.tab1_f = Figure(figsize=(7,5), dpi=100)
        self.tab1_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.tab1_f, master=self.tab1_frame)
        self.tab1_toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(self.tab1_frame)
        self.tab1_toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.tab1_canvas, self.tab1_toolbar_frame)
        self.tab1_toolbar.update()
        self.tab1_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.tab1_toolbar_frame.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.tab1_control_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.tab1_frame, text='Tab 1 Control Panel')
        self.tab1_control_frame.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)

        self.tab1_button = tk.Button(self.tab1_control_frame, text='Button')
        self.tab1_button.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)

        #define a figure canvas to go in tab 2
        self.tab2_f = Figure(figsize=(7,5), dpi=100)
        self.tab2_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.tab2_f, master=self.tab2_frame)
        self.tab2_toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(self.tab2_frame)
        self.tab2_toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.tab2_canvas, self.tab2_toolbar_frame)
        self.tab2_toolbar.update()
        self.tab2_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.tab2_toolbar_frame.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.tab2_control_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.tab2_frame, text='Tab 2 Control Panel')
        self.tab2_control_frame.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)

        self.tab2_button = tk.Button(self.tab2_control_frame, text='Button')
        self.tab2_button.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)



def main():
    root=tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    App(root).grid(row=0,column=0)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only want it to visually align,Just add some paddings in your code.

In your LeftFrame `.grid()`,add `pady=xx` and see the appearance manually.

```
self.left_frame.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=(22,0)) # This will be bad when you use DPI awareness.
```

[image]

PS:I try to use `self.ntbk.winfo_height()-self.tab1_frame.winfo_height()` to get the height of `tab`,but it actually not accurate.(It get `28`,but it looked not very nice.)

Edit:I find a way to directly set the `y` of `Tab1`,Now your code maybe can be:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
# import ctypes,sys 
#
# if sys.getwindowsversion().major == 10:
#     ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(2) # DPI AWARENESS


class App(tk.Frame):
    def getTabHeight(self):
        self.left_frame.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=(self.tab1_frame.winfo_y()-2,0))  # Get its height,I don't know why it need to minus 2,But in this way,no matter you use DPI awareness,It looked good.

    def __init__(self,parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        parent.deiconify()
        self.parent = parent

        #define and position the main panel on the left
        self.left_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.parent, text='Left Panel')

        #define and position the tab-enabled secondary panel on the right
        self.ntbk = ttk.Notebook(self.parent)
        self.ntbk.grid(row=0,column=1)

        #define internal frames for the tabs
        self.tab1_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.ntbk, text='Tab 1')
        self.tab2_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.ntbk, text='Tab 2')

        self.ntbk.add(self.tab1_frame, text='Tab 1')
        self.ntbk.add(self.tab2_frame, text='Tab 2')


        #Left panel children
        #define a figure canvas to go in the left panel
        self.left_f = Figure(figsize=(7,5), dpi=100)
        self.left_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.left_f, master=self.left_frame)
        self.left_toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(self.left_frame)
        self.left_toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.left_canvas, self.left_toolbar_frame)
        self.left_toolbar.update()
        self.left_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.left_toolbar_frame.grid(row=1,column=0)

        #define a control panel for the left panel to go below the figure
        self.left_control_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.left_frame, text='Left Control Panel')
        self.left_control_frame.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)

        self.left_button = tk.Button(self.left_control_frame, text='Button')
        self.left_button.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)


        #notebook children
        #define a figure canvas to go in tab 1
        self.tab1_f = Figure(figsize=(7,5), dpi=100)
        self.tab1_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.tab1_f, master=self.tab1_frame)
        self.tab1_toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(self.tab1_frame)
        self.tab1_toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.tab1_canvas, self.tab1_toolbar_frame)
        self.tab1_toolbar.update()
        self.tab1_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.tab1_toolbar_frame.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.tab1_control_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.tab1_frame, text='Tab 1 Control Panel')
        self.tab1_control_frame.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)

        self.tab1_button = tk.Button(self.tab1_control_frame, text='Button')
        self.tab1_button.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)

        #define a figure canvas to go in tab 2
        self.tab2_f = Figure(figsize=(7,5), dpi=100)
        self.tab2_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.tab2_f, master=self.tab2_frame)
        self.tab2_toolbar_frame = tk.Frame(self.tab2_frame)
        self.tab2_toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.tab2_canvas, self.tab2_toolbar_frame)
        self.tab2_toolbar.update()
        self.tab2_canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.tab2_toolbar_frame.grid(row=1,column=0)

        self.tab2_control_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.tab2_frame, text='Tab 2 Control Panel')
        self.tab2_control_frame.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)

        self.tab2_button = tk.Button(self.tab2_control_frame, text='Button')
        self.tab2_button.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=tk.E+tk.W)

        self.after(100,self.getTabHeight)



def main():
    root=tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    App(root).grid(row=0,column=0)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

In DPI awareness:
[image]